# PyTorch text classification model not improving

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, text-classification

I am training a simple LSTM model for binary text classification. Here is the model class:

```
class LSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocabulary_size, embeddings_size, num_classes):
        super(LSTM, self).__init__()

        self.vocabulary_size = vocabulary_size
        self.embeddings_size = embeddings_size

        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=vocabulary_size,
                                      embedding_dim=embeddings_size,
                                      padding_idx=0)

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=embeddings_size,
                            hidden_size=128,
                            num_layers=1,
                            batch_first=True)

        self.fc = nn.Linear(in_features=128,
                            out_features=num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.embedding(x)
        out, _ = self.lstm(out)
        out = out[:, -1]
        out = self.fc(out)
        out = torch.sigmoid(out)
        return out
```

I am using BCELoss and Adam optimizer created with the following code:

```
criterion = nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
```

This is the training loop that I am using:

```
train_steps = len(train_data_loader)
for epoch in range(epochs):
    train_loss = 0
    model.train()
    for i, (sequences, labels) in enumerate(train_data_loader):
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        sequences = sequences.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)

        outputs = model(sequences)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

        train_loss += loss.item()

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    print(f'Epoch {epoch+1}/{epochs}, Train Loss: {train_loss / train_steps:.4f}')
```

I have experimented with different datasets, number of epochs, learning rate, batch size. However, the model does not seem to learn - the loss is always around 0.7 and only the 0 class is predicted.

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: This is a question for https://datascience.stackexchange.com/. Since you don't mention anything about the data, I would start here: data size, proportion of the classes? a confusion matrix would help investigating what happens.

Comment: I have multiple datasets with a number of samples between 200k-400k sentences. The class proportion is balanced.

Comment: you should ask on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/, I'm not competent with DL but nobody else is going to answer here. If the classes are balanced I assume that there is bug, but it's also possible that the task is simply too hard. Also in case the classes are perfectly balanced there is probably some mistake with the data, but it's not related,